# MongoDB: How do I $sort on top-level doc field instance of created?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have an aggregate call in MongoDB (v4.2) where I'm doing a $lookup and $unwind of related sub-docs but I'm having problems figuring out how to sort. The sub-doc has a field called created and so does the top-level doc:

```
Wine.aggregate(
    [
        {
            "$match": {
                "user": ObjectId("<userId>")
            }
        },
        {
            "$sort": {
                "created": -1
            }
        },
        {
            "$lookup": {
                "from": "wineuniversals", // the collection name
                "localField": "wineUniversal", // field from the wines model
                "foreignField": "_id", // field how the two collections are linked
                "as": "uWineData" // the object property where the universal wine data is stored
            }
        },
        {
            "$unwind": {
                "path": "$uWineData"
            }
        }
    ]
).exec(function(err, wines) {...});
```

And here is an example of the docs it returns:

```
{
    "_id": "5dbbc408e78d867664213147",
    "photoURL": "51972ee99dec8f31cdb6ff8025a0d3d3",
    "user": "554f99352ee62248071b4d0f",
    "mode": "past",
    "wineUniversal": "5dce6038e78d8676642131fd",
    "hidden": false,
    "deleted": false,
    "eventBlindTasting": false,
    "quantity": 1,
    "groupDescription": "none",
    "comment": "Surprisingly tasty. You'd think it's be olonk based on the gimmicky label.",
    "scoreTotal": 91,
    "scoreOverallImpression": 4.2,
    "scoreFinish": 4,
    "scoreTaste": 4,
    "scoreAroma": 4.3,
    "lastUpdated": "2020-05-21T23:06:54.497Z",
    "created": "2020-05-21T23:06:54.498Z", // FIRST INSTANCE OF CREATED
    "uWineData": {
        "_id": "5dce6038e78d8676642131fd",
        "scoreCount": 1,
        "averageScore": 0,
        "userWines": ["5dbbc408e78d867664213147"],
        "expertScore2": "",
        "expertReviewer2": null,
        "expertScore1": "",
        "expertReviewer1": null,
        "currency": "USD",
        "commonPrice": 12,
        "additionalDetails": "",
        "designation": "",
        "category": "Red",
        "varietal": "Cabernet Sauvignon",
        "vineyard": "",
        "appellation": "California",
        "subRegion": "",
        "region": "California",
        "country": "United States",
        "wineryUrl": "https://www.thewalkingdeadwine.com",
        "winery": "The Walking Dead Wines",
        "vintage": "2016",
        "deleted": false,
        "lastUpdated": "2019-11-15T08:22:32.437Z",
        "created": "2019-11-15T08:22:16.579Z", // SECOND INSTANCE OF CREATED IN SUBDOC
        "__v": 1
    }
}
```

It looks like the `$sort` step is keying off the `created` field in the subdoc instead of the top-level doc's `created` field.

Is there a way to reference the `created` in the top-level doc so my $sort step orders the docs by the top level `created` field?

Comment: I highly believe it should be sorting on `created` field from top-level as if it has to sort on `created` from sub-doc then sort stage should have key as `uWineData.created`, Your `$unwind` probably might be disrupting the sorted order, why not to sort after `$unwind` ?

Comment: I've tried it in all different stages of the pipeline but I keep getting the messed up sort order.

Should I try adding a $project step and then maybe the $sort will affect the projected fields instead?

Comment: Well actually `$unwind` also preserving the sorted order, I don't correctly remember there is a stage that doesn't thought that is unwind, but anyhow it seems to work perfect :: https://mongoplayground.net/p/4Mqdn9M6X7w

Answer (score 0):

Ah ha! Turns out that adding the `preserverNullAndEmptyPathways: true` to the $unwind fixed the issue. Some of the top-level docs didn't have a sub-doc available yet (eg, the most recent docs hadn't yet had an _id linkage added to them, so there wasn't anything to $unwind, thus the Null/Empty issue).

```
{
    "path": "$uWineData",
    "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
}
```

Comment: So you don't actually have an issue with sorting order, rather have an issue with missing docs :-) :-)

Comment: LOL, embarassingly, yes!!